# create AVC_Intra from uncompressed in best quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, h.264, default-settings

I have some 720p uncompressed YUV video and I need to transcode this video into an AVC-Intra using the best possible quality.
The best possible Quality is needed, because the video probably will be decompressed and compressed several times during his lifetime.

Transcodingtime is not relevant.

I'm not sure, if I choose the right profile or the right level, preset an so on. I tried the following.

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 1280x720 -r 50 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i sourcevideo.yuv 
       -vcodec libx264 -intra -vb 100M -x264opts avcintra-class=100 
       -x264opts colorprim=bt709 -x264opts transfer=bt709
       -x264opts colormatrix=bt709-threads 7 -profile:v high10 
       -preset veryslow -acodec copy x264Video.mp4
```

Is are there some (probably missing) options I have to use or to change to get an better encoding quality?

Comment: Why not use lossless mode?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Uncompressed lossless need to much storage (we are talking about thousands of hours of video). And compressed lossless: there is still a huge need of storage and I'm not sure, which codec I should use (especially for future use), like: JPEG2000, FFV, h.264 lossless,....